# Form submit (file type) automatic with a link

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, hyperlink, submit

I need submit file when user click over link.

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: none;">
   <form id="uploadimage" name="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*">
      <input type="submit" class="btn-upload">
   </form>
</div>
<div>
   <a href="#" id="upload">Choose File</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#upload").on('click', function(e){
    $("input[name=image]").trigger('click');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("input[name=image]").change(function(){
    alert('Fire');
    ("#uploadimage").submit(function(){
        alert('In submit');
    });
});
```

When click over link, dialog open from select file, but not executed submit.

https://jsfiddle.net/qa73tgp7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to submit the form when the file is selected, in that case just call submit method of the form element in the change handler

```
$("#upload").on('click', function (e) {
    $("input[name=image]").trigger('click');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("input[name=image]").change(function () {
    $("#uploadimage").submit();
});

$("#uploadimage").submit(function(){
    alert('submit')
});
```

Note: May not work in IE<10

Comment: The problem  alert('In submit'); not fire (callback).

Comment: @Alexd2 sorry.. what do you mean

Comment: With 
 $("#uploadimage")[0].submit(function(){
        alert('In submit');
});
No show alert.

Comment: Yes, is the solution (please fixed your answer).